# :not selector doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, css

I have a problem with a menu in Wordpress and I've tried to write the code again on Codepen but I think I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't work neither there. Here is the problem:

```
    .nav-primary *:not(.sub-menu) a
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

If I use the **:not** selector my code doesn't work but if I delete it, it works with all the elements.

```css
.nav-primary a {
color: white;
background-color: #3A3F4E;
border: 0;
}

.nav-primary li:nth-child(2)
{
 font-family: Oswald;
}

.nav-primary li:first-child
{
 font-family: Oswald;
 position: relative;
 top: -1px;
}

.nav-primary li:first-child:hover
{
 position: relative;
 top: -1px;
}

.nav-primary .sub-menu a {
color: white;
background-color: #3A3F4E;
}

.nav-primary a:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #E56341;
}

.nav-primary > a
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-primary">
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <div class="sub-menu">
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can check [Here](https://codepen.io/Thatpsych/pen/MvNjpo) for `codepen` with the full code. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use `.nav-primary>a`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I've tried it on the website but I don't understand why it doesn't make any change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the a tag you want to target is children of .nav-primary and does not have another parent without .sub-menu class.

It works as below:

```css
.nav-primary a {
color: white;
background-color: #3A3F4E;
border: 0;
}

.nav-primary li:nth-child(2)
{
 font-family: Oswald;
}

.nav-primary li:first-child
{
 font-family: Oswald;
 position: relative;
 top: -1px;
}

.nav-primary li:first-child:hover
{
 position: relative;
 top: -1px;
}

.nav-primary .sub-menu a {
color: white;
background-color: #3A3F4E;
}

.nav-primary a:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #E56341;
}

.nav-primary *:not(.sub-menu) a
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-primary">
  <div class="dummy">
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>Home</a>
  </div>
</div>
```